# Get Priority wise Data based on request status using pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to run a query in SQL Server 2012 to select data from the table based on the request status.

am using the query with out including the where condition for fetching the current week of data.

Query with no where condition

```
select * from (SELECT ReqStatus,[priority] 
FROM WEEKDATA
group by ReqStatus,[priority] ,Raisedon

)p
pivot (
    Count([priority])
    For [priority] IN(Critical,High,Medium,Low)
 )
as pvt
```

**Result**

```
|ReqStatus | Critical| High| Medium| Low 
|----------|---------|-----|-------|----
| Approved |    1    |  0  |   0   | 0
| Assigned |    2    |  0  |   0   | 0
| Closed   |    2    |  1  |   1   | 1
| Rejected |    0    |  1  |   0   | 0
```

when I included the where condition in query for current week data

Query with Where Condition

```
select * from (SELECT ReqStatus,[priority] 
FROM WEEKDATA
    where DATENAME(wk,Raisedon)=DATENAME(wk,GETUTCDATE())
    group by ReqStatus,[priority] ,Raisedon

    )p
    pivot (
        Count([priority])
        For [priority] IN(Critical,High,Medium,Low)
     )
    as pvt
```

**Actual Result**

```
|ReqStatus | Critical| High| Medium| Low 
|----------|---------|-----|-------|----
| Assigned |    1    |  0  |   0   | 0
| Closed   |    0    |  0  |   1   | 0
```

am getting the above result because in current week i have only two status "assigned","Closed" in my table. But i also need the other request statuses like "Approved","Rejected" in the list with 0 values in the columns i.e. Critical ,High ,Medium,Low.

For Instance,

**Expected Result**

```
|ReqStatus | Critical| High| Medium| Low 
|----------|---------|-----|-------|----
| Approved |    0    |  0  |   0   | 0
| Assigned |    1    |  0  |   0   | 0
| Closed   |    0    |  0  |   1   | 0
| Rejected |    0    |  0  |   0   | 0
```

Comment: Do you have a configuration table anywhere that has a list of all the possible values for ReqStatus?

Comment: No,i have all the data in one table where it has ReqStatus,Priority and so on.

Comment: Ok. Without a table to join to for the statuses, Jatin's CTE option should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE with UNION ALL to add Status with value 0.

```
;WITH CTE_wd AS
(
    SELECT ReqStatus,[priority] 
    FROM WEEKDATA
    where DATENAME(wk,Raisedon)=DATENAME(wk,GETUTCDATE())
    group by ReqStatus,[priority] ,Raisedon
)   
select * from (SELECT ReqStatus,[priority] 
FROM CTE_wd
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT w.ReqStatus , '' AS [priority]
FROM WEEKDATA AS w
LEFT JOIN CTE_wd AS wd ON wd.ReqStatus = w.ReqStatus
WHERE wd.ReqStatus IS NULL
)p
pivot (
    Count([priority])
    For [priority] IN(Critical,High,Medium,Low)
 )
as pvt
```